# How to show network adapters with their statistics?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, command-line, networking

Is there any terminal command I can use to display all the network adapters like `eth0`, `wlano`and their data statistics like data transmitted & received?

Comment: What platform are you using? `uname -a`?

Comment: Debian & Ubuntu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways.

**The modern way**: use `ip`.

```
ip -s link
```

The output is pretty self-explanatory.

**The old way**: use `ifconfig`.

```
ifconfig -a
```

Also self-explanatory, but not as trivial to parse.

**The /proc way**:

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

Look at the `proc(5)` man page for more information (there really isn't much). This is a bit hard for human eyes, but very easy to parse.

Comment: yes I have used to proc way, Thanks for posting more possible ways.

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't state what OS/distro you are using, and since you didn't provide very much detail about what you're looking for, or why, or if you plan to use the information programatically, or just to satisfy curiousity, one of the more portable options is `netstat`, with the `-i` or `-s` options, depending on how much detail you need.

Both options work on Linux, Solaris, OS X (at least, as those are what I have handy to test on).  Here, for example, is output from `netstat -i`:

Linux:

```
[tim@evil]-bash-[841]$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth2       1500 0  10138332      0    889 0      15391815      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        16436 0      9762      0      0 0          9762      0      0      0 LRU
```

Solaris 11.1:

```
[tim@good]-bash-[853]$ netstat -i
Name  Mtu  Net/Dest      Address        Ipkts  Ierrs Opkts  Oerrs Collis Queue 
lo0   8232 loopback      localhost      77010  0     77010  0     0      0     
net0  1500 good.domain.net good.domain.net 18212603 0     10659618 0     0      0     
v0    1500 default       localhost      1109717 0     0      0     0      0     
v1    1500 default       localhost      1109717 0     0      0     0      0     
ipmp0 68   default       localhost      0      0     0      0     0      0     

Name  Mtu  Net/Dest                    Address                     Ipkts  Ierrs Opkts  Oerrs Collis
lo0   8252 localhost                   localhost                   77010  0     77010  0     0     
net0  1500 fe80::ea40:f2ff:fe3b:d470/10 fe80::ea40:f2ff:fe3b:d470   18212603 0     10659625 0     0     
v0    1500 default                     ::                          1109717 0     0      0     0     
v1    1500 default                     ::                          1109717 0     0      0     0     
ipmp0 1280 default                     ::                          0      0     0      0     0
```

Mac OS X:

```
[tim@chaos]-bash-[71]$ netstat -i
Name  Mtu   Network       Address            Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
lo0   16384 <Link#1>                       4008841     0  4008841     0     0
lo0   16384 localhost   ::1                4008841     -  4008841     -     -
lo0   16384 127           localhost        4008841     -  4008841     -     -
lo0   16384 localhost   fe80:1::1          4008841     -  4008841     -     -
gif0* 1280  <Link#2>                             0     0        0     0     0
stf0* 1280  <Link#3>                             0     0        0     0     0
en0   1500  <Link#4>    14:10:9f:e3:5a:4f 26610083     0 20157920     0     0
en0   1500  chaos.local fe80:4::1610:9fff 26610083     - 20157920     -     -
en0   1500  192.168.1     chaos.domain.ne 26610083     - 20157920     -     -
en3   1500  <Link#5>    32:00:14:c1:44:80        0     0        0     0     0
en4   1500  <Link#6>    32:00:14:c1:44:81        0     0        0     0     0
bridg 1500  <Link#7>    16:10:9f:3e:ea:00        0     0        1     0     0
p2p0  2304  <Link#8>    06:10:9f:e3:5a:4f        0     0        0     0     0
vboxn 1500  <Link#10>   0a:00:27:00:00:00        0     0        0     0     0
```

And if you really want detailed statistics, try `netstat -s` on for size.  Extremely verbose output, and just as portable as `netstat -i`.

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and type as

```
cat /proc/net/dev
```

For example , Here is mine.

```
august@august-OEM:~$  cat /proc/net/dev 
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:  495278    4025    0    0    0     0          0         0   495278    4025    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0: 36699927   39335    0    0    0     0          0         0  5536394   38245    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

Iftop produces a bar graph displaying the bandwidth consumption of each network connection (grouped by host).

The network interface can be selected using the `-i` parameter.

```
Listening on eth0             12.5kb                         25.0kb                          37.5kb                         50.0kb                    62.5kb
+------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------
server1.domain.local                         => host1.domain.local                                                                    1.33kb  1.33kb  1.33kb
                                             <=                                                                                       2.38kb  2.38kb  2.38kb                                                         
server1.domain.local                         => host17.domain.local                                                                   2.94kb  2.94kb  2.94kb
                                             <=                                                                                         320b    320b    320b   
10.7.7.255                                   => host45.domain.local                                                                       0b      0b      0b
                                             <=                                                                                         312b    312b    312b 
10.7.7.255                                   => host9.domain.local                                                                        0b      0b      0b
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TX:             cum:   1.07kB   peak:   4.27kb                                                                               rates:   4.27kb  4.27kb  4.27kb
RX:                     846B            3.30kb                                                                                        3.30kb  3.30kb  3.30kb
                                                                                                                                      7.57kb  7.57kb  7.57kb
```